# Mismatch .net framework between local (Windows 8.1) and server (Windows server 2003) generating sql exception

Tags: sql, .net, mismatch

I have asp .net 4 application running in development (local) on windows 8.1 & Visual Studio 2013, installed .net framework version 4.5, IIS Express

The production server is setup with windows server 2003 and  installed .net framework version 4.0, IIS 6
The web application Target Framework is .net framework 4

Lately i have encountered SqlException (0x80131904): "Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply".

This exception occurs only in production (on windows server 2003) where the runtime version is 4.0.30319.1022

In development (local on windows 8.1) where the runtime version is 4.0.30319.34011 this exception does not occur.

The SQL generated by LINQ in the server is different than the SQL generated in the local.
After a little research i found that different version of .net is causing this behavior.

As far as i know, the difference between the two versions is:
version 4.0.30319.1022 is built on .net framework 4.0 and version 4.0.30319.34011 is built on .net framework 4.5

Since .net framework 4.5 is not supported on windows server 2003, I would require targeting the older version on my dev machine.

Is there a way to target my dev instance to use the exact same .NET framework version or entities dll that is used in order to receive the same behavior in both dev & prod instances?

Thanks in advance,
Shai